# store database value into arry list using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I created a login application using struts2 and hibernate. I get login details from Login table and stored into list in hibernate dao class. That list is passed to the login_action class.In action class I am using iterator to get the value, but I want store the database value(not a object) in array list in dao class. How to store a value(ex:david,103) into array list in dao class

```
public class DAOClass {
    ...
    public List getPwd(LoginModel lm) {
        Session session=null;
        List pwdlist = null;
        session = sessionfactory.openSession(); 
        try {
            Query q=session.createQuery("from LoginModel l where UId='"+lm.getUname()+"'");
            pwdlist=q.list();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return pwdlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post relevant code, no clue about what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: DAO Class public List getPwd(LoginModel lm)
{Session session=null;List pwdlist=null;session=sessionfactory.openSession();
try{Query q=session.createQuery("from LoginModel l where UId='"+lm.getUname()+"'");
pwdlist=q.list();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
return pwdlist;}

Comment: In action Class public String execute() {try
{pwdlist=dao.getPwd(lm);Iterator<LoginModel> i= pwdlist.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){LoginModel lml= i.next();uname=lml.getUname();pwd=lm.getPwd();System.out.println("Db Uname="+uname);System.out.println("Db Pwd="+pwd);} see in my action action class the pwdlist contains only the loginmodel object value. but instead i need store the value not a object in the list. how do i store the db value into list in dao class?

Comment: I have edited your question, don't put code in comments. Try to make your post easy to read & understand for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can select only specific columns not the all the columns:

```
List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery("select column1, column2 from LoginModel l where UId='"+lm.getUname()+"'");
```

It will return list of object arrays where `column1 -> array[0]` and `column2 -> array[1]`.
This query is a bit faster because it only takes specific columns from the database. But you still need to iterate over collection to get values.

BTW use `setParameter` method to bind value to named query parameter. Using `setParameter` will prevent SQL injections.

```
List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery("select column1, column2 from LoginModel l where UId=:uid").setParameter("uid", lm.getUname());
```